# Split String at Last Space before Delimiter Using preg_split?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to use preg_split to split the following string at every space before a slash.  I know it will be a simple REGEX but I can't seem to figure it out using RegExr?

```
$string = 'DZ9243/XSHAGT FFGD JERSE XS2 DZ9232/MHAGT SUUMTE KNI M10 DZ9232/LHAGT SUMMER KNI L6';
```

I need to split the string at the last space before every / to give the following result:

```
DZ9243/XSHAGT FFGD JERSE XS2 
DZ9232/MHAGT SUUMTE KNI M10
DZ9232/LHAGT SUMMER KNI L6
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use a lookahead assertion. Read the documentation of [regex patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion:

```
$string = 'DZ9243/XSHAGT FFGD JERSE XS2 DZ9232/MHAGT SUUMTE KNI M10 DZ9232/LHAGT SUMMER KNI L6';
$pieces = preg_split('@ (?=[^ ]*/)@', $string);

print_r($pieces);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DZ9243/XSHAGT FFGD JERSE XS2
    [1] => DZ9232/MHAGT SUUMTE KNI M10
    [2] => DZ9232/LHAGT SUMMER KNI L6
)
```

#### The regex

```
@ (?=[^ ]*/)@
```

- `@` is the [`regex` delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php); usually `/` is used as delimiter but this regex attempts to match `/` and this is why it's better to use a different delimiter;
- it is followed by a space character; it is the space you want to use as delimiter for splitting the input string;
- `(` starts a group; the group is needed by the assertion;
- `?=` is forward looking positive assertion; it requires the group to match the input string but it does not consume the characters from the input string that matches the group;
- `[^ ]*/` is the group content; it matches any non-space character any number of times, followed by a `/`; this is the word that contains the slash (`/`);
- `)` ends the group.

All in all, the `regex` matches the spaces that are followed by a word that contain a slash but the word is not consumed; it is not included in the delimiter by `preg_split()`, only the space character is used.

Answer (score 0):

In case it doesn’t *have* to be regex …

```
$string = 'DZ9243/XSHAGT FFGD JERSE XS2 DZ9232/MHAGT SUUMTE KNI M10 DZ9232/LHAGT SUMMER KNI L6';

$parts = explode(' ', $string);
$results = [];
$i = -1;

foreach($parts as $part) {
  strpos($part, '/') !== false ? $results[++$i] = $part : $results[$i] .= ' ' . $part;
}

var_dump($results);
```